# how to gzip files using writelines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, gzip

I have a few files in my tmp folder that I want to gzip individually and upload to S3. The testList contains paths like `/tmp/files/File1`. SO fileName2, which I use for gzip.open() is `/tmp/files/File1.gz`. I want to gzip each file in the testList.

```
    for i in testList:
        fileName = i.replace("/tmp/files/", "") 
        fileName2 = i + '.gz'
        with open("path/to/file", 'rb') as orig_file:
            with gzip.open(fileName2, 'wb') as zipped_file:
                zipped_file.writelines(orig_file)
            bucket.upload_fileobj(zipped_file, fileName, ExtraArgs={'ContentType': "application/gzip"})
```

When I download the files from S3, they have a gz file type but I am unable to open them locally. It throws an error that the .gz file is empty and cannot be expanded. I believe the way I am writing content is incorrect.

How can I fix this?

Edit:

```
    for i in testList:
        fileName = i.replace("/tmp/files/", "") 
        fileName2 = i + '.gz'
        with open(i, 'rb') as f_in:
            with gzip.open(fileName2, 'wb') as f_out:
                shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
            f_out.upload_fileobj(zipped_file, fileName, ExtraArgs={'ContentType': "application/gzip"})
```

Even this, the gzip files are still not expandable.

Comment: *`f_out.upload_fileobj(zipped_file, [...]`* -- this last line in second code box must be a copy&paste mistake.

Comment: Nope, that's how I am trying to upload the file to s3. ```upload_fileobj``` is an S3 boto function and ```f_out```is the file I am trying to upload. Now I am not sure if ```f_out```really is the file or not. @Wolf

Comment: The last line will throw this error: `AttributeError: 'GzipFile' object has no attribute 'upload_fileobj'`. Please fix this! -1

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an open file in `orig_file`, not just lines.

I think your use case is about turning an existing file into a compressed one. So the following should be the relevant paragraph from the [*Examples of usage*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#examples-of-usage) section of the documentation:

> Example of how to GZIP compress an existing file:
>
> ```
> import gzip
> import shutil
> with open('/home/joe/file.txt', 'rb') as f_in:
>     with gzip.open('/home/joe/file.txt.gz', 'wb') as f_out:
>        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
> ```

Comment: Yup, the files are there and I want to gzip them. Is ```f_out``` what I can upload to s3 later? Please see the edit in the qs. I am still unable to expand the files

Comment: @Jbd Is it correct that you want to get *one* compressed archive of *multiple* files?

Comment: Nope, a different gz for each file in the ```testList```. That's why I am doing it in the loop

Comment: I see. Can you further specify what you get in your `.gz` file? Is it actually empty?

Comment: `I am unable to open it. It says` *You* or *it*? Please show us this **it** - Thanks :)

Comment: I am unable to open it. It says ```Unable to expand file.gz into Downloads. Error79: Inappropriate file type or format```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238385/discussion-between-wolf-and-jbd).